# Console print to label with Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, label, beacon

I try to make an app that shows the proximity of beacons. I made a `label` to receive this data, but I can't, and i want to just show "proximity" not all this data that shows in console. I try with `beacons[3]` but the program gives me a error.

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var metrosBeacon: UILabel!
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    let region = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: NSUUID(UUIDString: "FDA50693-A4E2-4FB1-AFCF-C6EB07647828")!, identifier: "MKT BEACONS")
    // Note: make sure you replace the keys here with your own beacons' Minor Values


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        locationManager.delegate = self
        if (CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() != CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse) {
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }
        locationManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], inRegion region: CLBeaconRegion){
        print (beacons)
        metrosBeacon.text = "/(beacons)"

    }}
```

**Console data :**

> [CLBeacon (uuid:<__NSConcreteUUID 0x12ee586c0> FDA50693-A4E2-4FB1-AFCF-C6EB07647828, major:10004, minor:54480, proximity:1 +/- 0.05m, rssi:-32)]

Thanks Guys!!

Comment: The error you get from calling beacons[3] may be happening because fewer than four beacons are visible.  I would use a solution like @eric-d shows in his answer where you access `beacons.first` to get the first one, and then access its proximity field.

Answer (score 2):

We see in `locationManager`'s signature that `beacons` is an array of CLBeacon objects:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], inRegion region: CLBeaconRegion)
```

And we see that you get one object in the array:

> [CLBeacon (uuid:<__NSConcreteUUID 0x12ee586c0> FDA50693-A4E2-4FB1-AFCF-C6EB07647828, major:10004, minor:54480, proximity:1 +/- 0.05m, rssi:-32)]

So, get this first object from the array, then get the value from the property:

```
if let beacon = beacons.first {
    print(beacon.proximity)
}
```

Of course, if you have several beacons in the array, you may use a loop:

```
for beacon in beacons {
    print(beacon.proximity)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`CLBeacon`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/clbeacon) is a subclass of [`NSObject`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/nsobject), thus is has a method called [`description()`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/nsobject/1418799-description), which returns an `NSString` containining the description of the object.

When you call `print(beacons)`, you're calling `print` on an argument of type `[CLBeacon]` (a.k.a. `Array<CLBeacon >`, or an Array of CLBeacon objects.). `print` doesn't itself know how to print `CLBeacon` objects, so it asks the `CLBeacon` for its `description()`, and prints that.

The output:

> [CLBeacon (uuid:<__NSConcreteUUID 0x12ee586c0> FDA50693-A4E2-4FB1-AFCF-C6EB07647828, major:10004, minor:54480, proximity:1 +/- 0.05m, rssi:-32)]

represents an array of a single `CLBeacon object, whose`description` is:

> CLBeacon (uuid:<__NSConcreteUUID 0x12ee586c0> FDA50693-A4E2-4FB1-AFCF-C6EB07647828, major:10004, minor:54480, proximity:1 +/- 0.05m, rssi:-32)

To get just the proximity, we can look into the [class documentation for `CLBeacon`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/clbeacon), and see that it has a [`proximity`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/clbeacon/1621554-proximity) variable we can get.

We can print all proximity with something like:

for beacon in beacons {
    print(beacon.proximity)
}